# How to get the current ScrollY position in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, scroll

I am trying to build a scroll that smoothly glides from one position to the next for a web page. (think of touch devices eg:- Android phones). I managed to make one and it works perfectly fine in Chrome. But the problem is IE 11.

There is no window.scrollY in IE 11. 
Is there any way to find the current Y position of the scroll bar in IE (9 and up)?

Comment: `document.body.scrollTop`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to find it using `document.body.scrollTop`. To make it backwards (or IE) compatible, try this:

```
var scrollTop = window.scrollY || document.body.scrollTop || 0;
```

And then use `scrollTop` as your variable.

Comment: `document.body.scrollTop` didn't work in my IE11 and (mac versions) Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 4):

Use `document.documentElement.scrollTop`

According to [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop#Browser_compatibility) scrollTop works this way with the root element. And the root element in the browsers is referenced by `document.documentElement` ([referece](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement)).

This should work both in IE and in modern browsers.